# Is it possible to fill an image within selected area inside canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have multiple polygon shapes,and the requirement is to fill images inside this drawn polygons. i have searched a lot on this,but only rectangle,curve,circles are shown in examples . But in my case all images have custom polygon shapes. an example is given below : `

```
     ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineTo(8, 109);
      ctx.lineTo(5, 109);
      ctx.lineTo(14, 112);
      ctx.lineTo(31, 119);
      ctx.lineTo(42, 129);
      ctx.lineTo(89, 150);
      ctx.lineTo(131, 140);
      ctx.lineTo(222, 199);
      ctx.lineTo(225, 238);
      ctx.lineTo(268, 270);
      ctx.lineTo(283, 253);
      ctx.lineTo(320, 275);
      ctx.lineTo(322, 298);
      ctx.lineTo(342, 332);
      ctx.lineTo(343, 354);
      ctx.lineTo(320, 392);
      ctx.lineTo(0, 393);
      ctx.lineTo(8, 109);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.lineWidth = 5;
      ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
      // ctx.fill();
// ctx.drawImage(img);
// ctx.drawImage(img, 170,80,80,320,320,170);
```

Filling with color working perfectly,but instead i need to fill it with images. Is it possible ?

Comment: I got the answer : it can be implemented using - createPattern()

Comment: It would be great if you would add your complete answer and accept it so that when someone else searches for this, they can find it all right here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ctx.createPattern(); will set image inside the closed path